# getModuleById parameter parsing

Tags: module

So when getting a module for rendering inside a component this is not working:

```
$mod = ModuleHelper::getModuleById(123);
```

but this:

```
$mod = ModuleHelper::getModuleById("123");
```

That's because inside Joomlas getModuleById function the type is declared to string:

```
if ((string) $modules[$i]->id === $id) {
```

Does that makes sence? Whats the purpose of that?

Comment: No purpose. It's just an example of code not being reviewed before being merged.